# Size of vector returned by sizeof() in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, sizeof

I was just experimenting with C++ and here is a code snippet that I executed:

```
int main() {

    std::vector<int> data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::cout << data.size() << " " << sizeof(data) << " " << sizeof(data[0]) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:
5 16 4
Now I know that size() returns the number of elements in vector ie. 5 here and sizeof() returns the number of bytes occupied by the variable. sizeof(data[0]) makes sense to be 4 bytes as it is an int and visual studio compiler assigns 4 bytes to it but I dont understand why sizeof(data) returns 16. I was calculating 20. Any explanation for this would be helpful.

Comment: How are you calculating 20? _"`sizeof()` returns the number of bytes occupied by the variable"_ This isn't quite true, at least not in the way that you're interpreting it. `sizeof` returns the size of the _type_ of the provided expression. Using `sizeof` on any expression that has type `vector<X>` will return the exact same value, regardless of the runtime size of that vector.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<T>` uses dynamic storage the size of which can be changed, as stated in documentation. unlike `std::array<T, size>` it's not an aggregate type and stored data isn't part of class's storage. `sizeof` returns the size of storage, which is a constant determined at time of compilation, according to C++ rules.

Ergo, you compare apples to oranges. `sizeof` returns size of vector's type in bytes, Member function `size()` returns number of created elements. Member function `capacity()` would return allocated memory, which can be larger than `size()*sizeof(T)`.